# signalR javascript runtime Object does not support property

Tags: java, signalr

I am a C# algorithmic programmer trying to integrate `SignalR` so that I can send progress messages on long running codes.

The following simple prototype fails on

`helloConnection.sayHelloToAll("Hello all!");`

with JavaScript error "Object doesn't support property......" although a right click on `helloConnection`. clearly shows the method. No similar instance of this message that I have found applies to my example.

Please can someone help: I have spent weeks of frustration trying to make this work. Here is the client. It is in my Master page because my messages will go on the header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <link href="Styles/SiteBlue.css" rel="stylesheet" e="text/css" />
    <title> Seeker-Home Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">      </script>
    <script src="Scripts/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="SignalR/Hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(); //document ready
        var helloConnection = $.connection.seekerHub;

        helloConnection.client.sayHelloToMe = function (message) {
            alert(message);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            helloConnection.sayHelloToAll("Hello all!");
        });
        function displayPopup() {
            alert("Hello, world.");
        };
    </script>
```

and here is the hub

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SignalR
{
      public class SeekerHub : Hub
      {
            public void SayHelloToAll(string message)
            {
                  Clients.All.sayHelloToMe(message);
                  var callingClient = Context.ConnectionId;
            }
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call the client method `sayHelloToMe` from the client.

Replace this line of code:

```
helloConnection.client.sayHelloToMe = function (message) {
    alert(message);
};
```

with this:

```
helloConnection.on('sayHelloToMe ', function(message) {
    alert(message);
});
```

This way you actually have a handler on the client side listening to the server side with the trigger being `sayHelloToMe`

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Now that its working it is great!! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark this answer if you think this has solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can overide `OnConnected` in the Hub to see if your client connects to server

```
public override Task OnConnected() 
{
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub.onconnected(v=vs.118).aspx